# Multiple BaseControllers with IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, ioc-container

I read [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40102/using-a-basecontroller-in-mvc-asp-net-to-reuse-the-repository), and the answer helps me but not completely. What if I have 20 repositories with different responsibilities, like for example:

ICountryRepository
ICityRepository

and

IUserRepository
IPersonRepository

I can have all the methods of this repositories in the BaseController, but I would prefer something like having a TerritoriesBaseController, whit the ICoutnryRepository and ICityRepository and PersonsBaseController IUserRepository and IPersonRepository, than inherits from BaseController.7

My problem is that, if I have a controller that wants to use the TerritoryBaseController and PersonBaseController, I can't make it inherit from both controllers.

The reason why I want to separate the base controllers, is for structure, order and for not having a controller with 200 methods, but 20 controllers with 10 methods, and with separated responsibilities.

Some ideas how can it be organized?

**EDIT:**

I think I didn't explain the question properly.

Let's take this example:

I have a project with IoC, and let's say I have 4 repositories.

ICountryRepository, ICityRepository, IUserRepository, IPersonRepository.

I have a controller that needs methods of the 4 repositories, for example, UserController, it will use IUserRepository and IPersonRepository to save the user, and ICountryRepository and ICityRepository to show a list of countries and cities that the user has to select.

I also have a BaseController, where i have the generic methods of the controllers, and UserController inherits of BaseController, so:

```
UerController : BaseController
```

What I would like to do is, have a TerritoriesBaseController, where i would have all the methods that are repeated in my controlers of ICouuntrRepository and ICityRepository, like:

```
public JsonResult GetCountriesSelectList()
{
    List<Country> listCountryLanguage = _applicationCountry.GetAll().ToList();
    return Json(new SelectList(listCountryLanguage, "IdCountry", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the same with IPersonRepository and IUserRepository, with a UserBaseController.

But I Can't use:

```
Usercontroler : BaseController, TerritoriesBaseController, UserBaseController
```

Because in c# you can only inherit from one class.

How can i reorganize it or what solution can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if I have 20 repositories with different responsibilities,

If you have a controller that needs to use 20 repositories, there is something wrong with your design. That controller will violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

There are a few solutions to this problem:

- Split the logic in the controller up into multiple smaller, more focused controllers that each have just a few dependencies.
- Move part of the logic to an [aggregate service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). In your case your controller probably has a lots of business logic in it. You should extract that business logic to a different class. The [command/handler pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) is very suited for implementing business logic.
- If you have code that uses multiple repositories, there's a special well-known pattern that for this: the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). What you can do is make those repositories accessible as properties on a Unit of Work class and inject only that unit of work.

**UPDATE**

> UserController, it will use IUserRepository and IPersonRepository to
>   save the user, and ICountryRepository and ICityRepository to show a
>   list of countries and cities that the user has to select.

In that case you should extract the logic of saving the user into a new class and you should do the same with the logic for getting the list of countries. In that case your `UserController` will only depend on two more specific dependencies and the code inside the `UserController` will be minimized.

Don't use base controllers. Using base classes is often a sign of a glitch in your design. Your code becomes much harder to test when using base classes, and those base classes will often grow into god classes. Besides, you already noticed that multiple inheritance is not possible in .NET.

So what you can do is the following:

```cs
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private ICommandHandler<SaveUser> saveUserHandler;
    private IQueryProcessor queryProcessor;

    public UserController(ICommandHandler<SaveUser> saveUserHandler,
        IQueryProcessor queryProcessor)
    {
        this.saveUserHandler = saveUserHandler;
        this.queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
    }

    public ActionResult Save(SaveUserViewModel model)
    {
        this.saveUserHandler.Handle(new SaveUser
        {
            UserId = model.UserId,
            Name = model.UserName,
        });

        Redirect("/Success");
    }

    public JsonResult Countries()
    {
        var listCountryLanguage = queryProcessor.Execute(new GetAllCountries());
        return Json(new SelectList(listCountryLanguage, "IdCountry", "Name"),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Do note that for this example I use the [query/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and [command/handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) patterns, but that's optional.

Comment: Hi, I did not explain myself correctly, I edited the question, but i think that your first option is what I'm looking for, but I dont' know how to do it.